# How can I include my own JS/jQuery function's file globally in my Angular 5 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a JS/jQuery function's file & want to use it in all components in my Angular 5 project. So, how can I use it's functions in my project.

Note: I've already installed jQuery and can use it as well in my typescript. But I want to use functions from my own JS/jQuery file (app.js) in typescript. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can include them in the file assets (or somewhere else) and further add them in `.angular-cli.json`, the path should be correct one. You can add a folder called js inside assets and place such files there. And modify the file `.angular-cli.json`  like

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "angular-test"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        ".htaccess",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "assets/css/styles.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "assets/js/app.js"   /* add all such files HERE */
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/env.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/env.ts"
      }
    }
  ],

  ...
}
```

Comment: @Komal_Chandra, update me whether it worked in your case

Comment: no it's not working. How can I import this JS file (app.js) in my typescript? Like to import jQuery plugin, I used "import * as $ from 'jquery".

Comment: Usually jquery is not much used in Angular projects. However its required for some effects and all. Such simple tasks can be done by adding such files in assets, and mention in angular-cli.json. There is no need to install jquery package at all